# Can I Still Use 2nd Hot Wire In Panel If I Rewired Panel For 120V?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, 240v, inverter

I'm working on a cabin that only has electricity supplied to it from a generator room outside the house. The wire coming into the house was 8/3 with the 2 hots going to separate sides of the panel and a shared neutral. I've installed an inverter(120V) with batteries and have rewired the panel in the house to a single 6/2 wire from the inverter.

I'm currently using one of the hot wires and neutral from the 8/3 wire that used to be hooked up to the panel to send power back into the inverter when the generator is on and charge the batteries. The inverter will use the power from this wire to run the panel (when generator is on) and any power that is left is used to charge the batteries.

Can I use the second hot wire coming in from the generator for anything or will I have a problem with the shared neutral? It looks like my generator has two 30A breakers so I assume when this was originally hooked to the panel each side had its own 30A? Does this mean I could do something like dedicating the electric water heater and well pump(120V) to the other hot wire using the same neutral?

Generator Room
[image: Generator Room Outside House]

Panel Inside House(with old 240 hooked up)
[image: Old 240V Wiring In Panel]

Inverter + Batteries
[image: 120V Inverter]

Comment: what size wire is the neutral

Comment: As noted on your other question, without all the info you've just removed, there's no way to answer your question. You're not helping us help you...

Comment: Please stop destroying useful information in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

A 120V cabin is perfectly reasonable; I live in one.

Your concern is overloading the neutral, and that is a valid concern.  Here's the rule:

The neutral wire can only be shared **if both hot wires are sourced from the same 120/240V supply**.

What you cannot do, for instance, is use a 120V generator to feed black+white, and another 120V generator or solar inverter to feed red+white.

The sharing of neutral, called a *Multi-Wire Branch Circuit* or MWBC, actually harkens back to the days of Edison and DC power. Edison supplied houses with neutral, -110V and +110V. This arrangement greatly reduced *voltage drop*, which was a huge problem on the DC system since transformers are not possible in DC.

Lights were connected between either DC pole and neutral.  Motors were connected between the other DC pole and neutral.  Neutral carried only differential voltage.  Which is how MWBCs work today.  Except the voltage flips 120 times a second!

When you have sources that are not lock-synced, they are flipping at different times. Drifting in and out of phase with each other, sometimes in phase, sometimes partly out of phase and other times opposite phase. While you might think "oh, that will average out", the problem is that wire heating *is the square of* current. So when it is at 200% overload, it is adding 400% heating to the wire. Even if that only occurs half the time, half of 400% is still way more than 100%.

Comment: Voltage flips 120 times a second! between two phase ,and 60 for each phase. A generator that delivers 2 phases will have lock-sync.